# How do i know if an account is unlocked in geth

Tags: go-ethereum

Is there any API available to check whether an account is **locked/unlocked** in geth ? If i try to unlock an account that is already in unlocked state, does geth look out for the **cached decrypted key** , instead of **decrypting  each time** ?

Also what if there are **concurrent requests for unlocking** of the same account (which is initially locked) ? Can this result in out of Memory error ?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Answer (score 6):

At the `geth` console (invoked by `geth attach`), run `personal.listWallets` to see a list of wallets and their statuses:

```
[{
    accounts: [{
        address: "0xae9c2ed2209d2228c131cc99569233a5d506770b",
        url: "..."
    }],
    status: "Unlocked",
    url: "..."
}]
```

You're interested in the wallet status field which can be either "Locked" or "Unlocked".

Comment: web3.personal does not provide listWallets under nodejs @aupiff

Comment: I was talking about the `geth` console in my response. `geth` console commands are not identical to those defined in the web3.js library.

Answer (score 0):

[`web3.geth.personal.list_wallets()`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.geth.html?highlight=listwallets#web3.geth.personal.list_wallets).

> Delegates to personal_listWallets RPC Method
>
> Returns the list of wallets managed by Geth.

```
>>> web3.geth.personal.list_wallets()
[{
    accounts: [{
        address: "0x44f705f3c31017856777f2931c2f09f240dd800b",
        url: "keystore:///path/to/keystore/UTC--2020-03-30T23-24-43.133883000Z--44f705f3c31017856777f2931c2f09f240dd800b"
    }],
    status: "Unlocked",
    url: "keystore:///path/to/keystore/UTC--2020-03-30T23-24-43.133883000Z--44f705f3c31017856777f2931c2f09f240dd800b"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the same result from inside node.js or the browser use this.
Im using the `personal_listWallets` JSON-RPC method in a waitable promise'ify function.
Just call `listWallets().then();`

```js
async function listWallets() {
    try {
        const result = await sendRPC_personal_listWallets();
        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
}

function sendRPC_personal_listWallets() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        web3.currentProvider.send({ method: "personal_listWallets", params: [], jsonrpc: "2.0", id: new Date().getTime() },
            function (error, result) { if (error) { reject(error); } else { resolve(result); } });
    }
    );
}

let wallets;
listWallets().then((r) => { console.log("ID:", r.id); wallets = r.result; console.log("Accounts:", wallets); });
```