# geth: How could I list already unlocked accounts?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using `geth` via third party application. I want to verify that specific Ethereum accounts are already unlocked or not, since unlocking an account can be timeout.

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "password");
```

**[Q]** Is there any way to verify that specific Ethereum accounts are already unlocked?

---

Please note that following script:

```
var Personal = require('web3-eth-personal');

Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

if(!web3.isConnected()){
    console.log("notconnected");
    process.exit();
}

console.log(web3.personal
```

Returns, which does not have `personal.listWallets`:

```
Personal {
  _requestManager:
   RequestManager {
     provider:
      HttpProvider {
        host: 'http://localhost:8545',
        timeout: 0,
        user: undefined,
        password: undefined,
        headers: undefined },
     polls: {},
     timeout: null },
  newAccount: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'personal_newAccount' },
  importRawKey: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'personal_importRawKey' },
  unlockAccount: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'personal_unlockAccount' },
  ecRecover: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'personal_ecRecover' },
  sign: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'personal_sign' },
  sendTransaction:
   { [Function: send]
     request: [Function: bound ],
     call: 'personal_sendTransaction' },
  lockAccount: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'personal_lockAccount' },
  listAccounts: [Getter],
  getListAccounts: { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] } }
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'unlocked'? How can an account be locked / unlocked?

Comment: In order to send Tx we need to unlock an account: `personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "password");` @LauriPeltonen

Comment: Ah in that sense :)

Comment: not necessarily exactly the same but some of the suggestions in [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6903/unlocking-accounts-and-making-transactions-in-web3-js?lq=1) may help

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/32059.

Running `personal.listWallets` displays a list of all your wallets and shows their status (`locked` or `unlocked`).

Comment: `web3.personal` does not provide listWallets under `nodejs` @Fischa7

Answer (score 0):

personal.listAccounts  This will give you a list of address's within a wallet.

Answer (score 0):

```js
personal.listWallets.filter(function (wallet) {return wallet.status === 'Unlocked'})
```

---

Unfortunately, it doesn't support advanced javascript features ([arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)), now (geth v1.10.0) . So it's not possible to write it as below concise way:

```js
personal.listWallets.filter({status} => status === 'Unlocked')
```

Maybe in the future.